# get_template_directory_uri() generates wrong path

Tags: css, javascript, uploads

I've uploaded a wordpress site but it's missing javascript and css. The links on the head still have the local path (`src='https://localhost...'`) and not the new ones. So I guess it has to do with get_template_direcory_uri() that I use in fucntions.php to apply my javascript/jquery,bootstrap,css etc.

How yo fix that?

I've tried adding to config.php:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

and

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://...' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://...' );
```

but they didn't help...

Comment: Can you show how you enqueue your styles and scripts? Please make sure to use formatting, you can see how to do it from my edit

Comment: Have you updated the all of your site links after the migration? Please show us your `enqueue` code

Comment: Have you set the correct URL in _Settings > General_?

Comment: I have the same problem. In a development environment I want to use settings different from those in wp_options table. In the back end I do see the grayed out versions of site_url and home conforming the setting in wp_config.php. However, 
get_template_directory_uri() just returns the one in wp_settings, not the one in wp_config.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your URL change up in phpMyAdmin with SQL language:

```
# Change website url
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-site.com','http://www.new-site.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

# Change GUID URL
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.old-site.com','http://www.new-site.com');

# Change url of medias, post, page, etc.
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://www.old-site.com','http://www.new-site.com');

# Change meta data url
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://www.old-site.com','http://www.new-site.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Beware that this can break your site even further. WordPress stores some data serialized (especially in the `postmeta` and `options` table). Running these queries will destroy the serialized strings. Instead, you can use the [WP-CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) (especially with the `--precise` flag) or plugins such as [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/).